# Bootstrap select not changing icon set

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am using [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) select js plugin. In the documentation it says that you can change the icons with adding data attributes to select tag. I did it like it is suggested in the docs:

```
<select name="position" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-max-options="2" data-iconBase="ion" data-tickIcon="ion-checkmark-round" required>
```

But the html that is being created with the select element still has glyphicon icon, so nothing gets rendered. Has anyone managed to change the icons in this package?

Comment: that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fix you `data-` attributes too `data-icon-base="ion"` and `data-tick-icon="ion-checkmark-round"`